# COALESCE types text and integer cannot be matche

Tags: sql, postgresql

Basically I have a column item_importance based on it's value I want to return an output `zone_index`

```
CASE
            WHEN item_importance in ('kvi', 'super_kvi') 
                THEN 
                    data->>'zone_index'
            WHEN item_importance in ('non_kvi_1', 'non_kvi_2') 
                THEN 
                    data->>'zone_price_diff_non_kvi'
                    
        END as zone_index
```

The following query works, but on the output if `data->>'zone_index'` or `data- >>'zone_price_diff_non_kvi'` is null, it returns null. How can I make the default value if null to be 0 for `zone_index`

I tried `COALESCE(data->>'zone_index', 0)`

I get

> ERROR:  COALESCE types text and integer cannot be matched
> LINE 9:      COALESCE(data->>'zone_index', 0)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know you table or data, but clearly one of the branches of the `CASE` expression is outputting a text value.  Therefore, coalescing that value to `0`, an integer, does not make sense.  Try using `'0'` instead (or any text value):

```sql
CASE WHEN item_importance IN ('kvi', 'super_kvi')
     THEN COALESCE(data->>'zone_index', '0')  -- or any text literal value
     WHEN item_importance IN ('non_kvi_1', 'non_kvi_2')
     THEN data->>'zone_price_diff_non_kvi'
END as zone_index
```

**Edit:**

If you are *certain* that `data->>'zone_index'` would always be an integer, you could also use:

```
COALESCE(CAST(data->>'zone_index' AS int), 0)
```

But then the other branch of the `CASE` expression would also require a cast to integer.  All branches of a `CASE` expression always must have the same type, as a general rule.

Comment: Is there a way to convert the string value to integer using CAST? I tried that also, but ran into syntactical issues.

Comment: THEN COALESCE(data->>'zone_index'::int, 0) doing so gives invalid input syntax

Answer (score 0):

Add a `nullif` function call to convert a JSON `null` to an SQL NULL:

```
coalesce(
   CAST(
      nullif(data->>'zone_index', 'null') AS integer
   ),
   0
)
```